# Conflicts between jQuery custom plugins using internal variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm starting to use a lot of plugins to enhance sites quickly but I'm still getting used to jQuery. Occasionally I'm getting conflicts. One of the most commonly used words is ***settings***, ***self*** and ***dat*** as an internal variable used for self reference.

Take the following code:

```
    (function ($)
    {
        var cheese = this;
        var var1;
        var var2;
        $.fn.cheesetest = function (text) {
            cheese.var1 = text;
            cheese.var2 = text;
            console.log(cheese.var1 + ", " + cheese.var2);
        }
    }(jQuery));

    (function ($)
    {
        var cheese = this;
        var var1;
        var var2;
        $.fn.cheese2 = function (text) {
            cheese.var1 = text;
            console.log(cheese.var1 + ", " + cheese.var2);
        }
    }(jQuery));
```

I run the code with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').cheesetest('panther');
    $('h2').cheese2('tiger');
 })
```

And the output is:

*panther, panther
   tiger, panther*

In short, it seems cheese (or self or settings in some plugins) is referring to the shared jQuery scope and not that plugin.

The question is: how do I use internal variables so that

```
var self
```

..in one plugin doesn't conflict with self or settings variables in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is because you are using:

```
var cheese = this;
```

Here *this* will refer to the *window* object and essentially you are creating a global variable `cheese` here - that's why there is a *conflict*.

```js
(function($) {
  var cheese = {};
  $.fn.cheesetest = function(text) {
    cheese.var1 = text;
    cheese.var2 = text;
    console.log(cheese.var1 + ", " + cheese.var2);
  }
}(jQuery));


(function($) {
  var cheese = {};
  $.fn.cheese2 = function(text) {
    cheese.var1 = text;
    console.log(cheese.var1 + ", " + cheese.var2);
  }
}(jQuery));


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').cheesetest('panther');
  $('h2').cheese2('tiger');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
```